# Date function giving a warning on my staging server

Tags: php, date

I am using date function in my php script like this

```
 $doy = date('z') + 1;
 $edition = date('Y') . $doy;
```

On my local machine its not giving me any warning but on my staging server it gives the following warning why is it so . How can I remove this ?

Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for '2.0/DST' instead

Comment: Why do people keep ignoring clear error messages even when they contain the exact instructions on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

That's exactly what you must do...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

Or in php.ini:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

Obviously you can use whatever timezone you want.

Answer (score 0):

before calling date() set your default timezone with date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev').  The list of supported timezones is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: you may set this as the first statement in your index script (or any other entry point of your app)

Comment: If you're always going to use a single time zone, it's better to set it in your php.ini file, rather than setting it in your code. (see answer by @Matthew)

Answer (score 0):

You can just set your default time zone on top of the page

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

If you just want to use it temporarily

```
   $dateTime = new DateTime();
   $DateTimeZone = timezone_open ( 'America/Chicago' );
   $dateTime->setTimezone( $DateTimeZone );
   echo $dateTime->format("Y") , ($dateTime->format("z") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want day of year or time zone? Since you named it $doy I thought you wanted Day Of Year.  However, all the error messages you get speak of time zone.  On page 139 of Oreilly Book there is a date function format specifiers list and the lower case "z" which you used is for day of year.  Elsewhere in the book I read that an upper case "Z" is for time zones.  It appears there is some kind of glitch going on when the error message replies on time zones, yet your code specifies day of year.

The book to which I refer is "Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, & CSS."

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions in your answers.

Answer (score -2):

This is caused by the error settings on your staging server.
You can remove this output by changing the error reporting level

Example:

```
// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

You can find more info on the php website: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

But you can also just solve this Message like Baba has posted.

Comment: This isn't the correct way to solve this. Show ALL errors on the development server. Fix them. Then show NO errors in production (but still log them of course).